# Angular how to style input type file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have already seen many questions about style an input type file but I can't find out to do It in angular.

So how can I style inside an angular app an input type file?

This is my code inside and html page:

```
<input type="file" ngf-select ng-model="vm.attachment" name="file" accept="application/pdf" ngf-max-size="5MB" ngf-model-invalid="errorFile">
```

I have already tried with (after my input file hidde):

```
<md-button id="uploadButton" class="md-raised md-primary"> Choose Files </md-button>

link (scope, element, attrs) {
  const input   = element.find('#fileInput');
  const button = element.find('#uploadButton');

  if (input.length && button.length) {
    button.click((e) => input.click());
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, my link function doesn't work because I'm using controller and inside the page retrieve error if i put this function

Comment: You can use the `ngf-select` directive on a button, for example, check the example from their github doc page http://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/xxo3sk41/590/

        `<button ngf-select ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*">
            Select Picture</button>`

Comment: seems that works! Post an answer and I accept It

Comment: the only thing that I can't do is when I select a file I would like to see the name of the file, is possibile? @Fissio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ngf-select directive on a button - check the example from their github doc page: https://jsfiddle.net/danialfarid/xxo3sk41/590

The `ng-model` file has a `name` attribute that you can use to display the filename:

```
<button ngf-select ng-model="picFile" accept="image/*"> Select Picture</button>
File name: {{picFile.name}}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not common to style a input file. I prefer to make it hidden, set a custom component and point its events to the input file. So, I can style this component as much as we want.

**Input file hidden**

Make it hidden with display: none

```html
<input type="file" id="input-file" name="file" style="display: none">
```

**My custom component**

Add an onclick event, so a click here will point to our input file.

```html
<md-button onclick="document.querySelector('#input-file').click()" class="md-raised md-primary"> Choose Files </md-button>
```

> That's it, until here the job is done. But, if we also want to catch the document's name add onchange event to the input file.

```html
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().onchange(this)" id="input-file" name="file" style="display: none">
<span>{{theFile.name}}</span>
```

```js
$scope.onchange = function (sender) {
  $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
    $scope.theFile = sender.files[0]; 
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach

```css
input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 0;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(91, 105, 194);
  border-radius: 8px;
}

input[type=file]::file-selector-button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(54, 61, 115);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input
    type="file"
    [accept]="'.pdf'"
    multiple/>
  <label>Select file</label>
</div>
```